# Confused on helping and wandering monsters in munchkin zombies

Tags: munchkin

There are 5 players. Player 1 kicks down door, there is a monster he needs help with. A player agrees to help. Can the other three players all use a wandering monster card and a monster card?

If so are the two players now fighting 4 monsters or 3 because the first monster dies at the moment the player said he/she would help?

If the two beat all the monsters, do both get levels per monster killed or just player one?

Comment: Even the player who fight can add more wandering monsters...

Answer (score 9):

The two players would have to defeat all 4 monsters. After getting help, the other players are allowed a reasonable amount of time to interfere before you can claim levels and treasure.

And just like normal getting help, only player 1 gets the levels, but both share the treasure.

Comment: As a point to sharing treasure, they still share treasure according to the initial agreement! If you helped for "2 of 4 treasures" rather than "half" that's all you'd get, even if there are loads more treasures now.